# Display custom method field in Admin Display

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have some Django model that has a list of numbers as a field. I compute some statistics on the field using a custom method in the model. These models are displayed on the admin panel as an InlineAdminModel "embedded" in a parent object. Is there a way to display this custom method value in the admin panel *when modifying the parent model*, this would obviously only apply to ones that have already been created.

e.g. (truncated)

```
class ListModel(models.Model):
    number_list = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length = 20)
    def sum(self):
        return sum([int(s) for s in number_list.split(',')]) 

class ListModelAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ListModel
    list_display = ('sum') #works fine for displaying the ListModel 
    fields = ['number_list', 'sum'] #Obviously Doesn't work, but demonstrates
    #what I want to accomplish. sum wouldn't be settable but displayed when 
    #number_list is updated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fields` is for editable fields. Use [readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) instead.

Comment: I went through that doc 3 or 4 times and didn't see it, guess that means its time to sleep